# How to prevent <select> from opening with custom style?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've made this custom style `<select>` box by following [this guide](https://moderncss.dev/custom-select-styles-with-pure-css/) and creating a custom `<option>` list using `<div>` and `<a>` tags for a customized style. I have managed to get it to work to what I want but the problem is that preventing the system default `<option>` list still opens.

I know I could just change the elements and CSS style to buttons, divs etc instead of `<select>` for a custom style but I don't really want to change the code around too much. I am aware that using `:disabled` or `.blur()` is an option but using `:disabled` is not possible and `.blur()` is the most effective method but I need a smooth transition so it doesn't show.

```js
// This function checks if HTML Attribute exits.
jQuery.fn.hasAttr = function(name) {
  let attr = this.attr(name);
  return typeof attr !== "undefined" && attr !== false;
};

$(document).ready(() => {

  const selectWrapper = $("div.select-wrapper");
  const selectList = $("div.option-list");
  const selectTag = $("select#countries");
  const selectTagOption = selectTag.children("option");
  
  // create a <a></a> list for the custom list div based on the <option></option> list
  selectTagOption.each((i, el) => {
    let a = $(document.createElement("a"));
    let o = $(el);
    
    a.attr("data-value", o.attr("value"));
    a.html(o.html());
    a.appendTo(selectList);
  });
  
  const anchorList = selectList.children("a");
  
  // --- see .blur() works well but not smooth ---
  // it shows it first then it closes it immediately but NOT quick enough that it's not visible.
  selectTag.click((e) => {
    $(e.target).blur();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  
  // click event fires when clicked anywhere inside the .select-wrapper div or the <select> tag.
  $(document).on("click", [selectTag, selectWrapper], (e) => {
    
    // toggle custom list to open/close
    let div = selectList;
    let state = div.attr("data-open");
    
    if (state === "false") {
      div.css("display", "block");
      div.attr("data-open", "true");
    } else {
      div.css("display", "none");
      div.attr("data-open", "false");
    }
  });
  
  // close the list when clicked outside of the select box
  $(window).click((e) => {
    let ele = $(e.target);
    if (!(ele.is(selectTag) || ele.is(selectWrapper) || ele.is(selectWrapper) || ele.is(anchorList))) {
      if (selectList.attr("data-open") === "true") {
        selectList.css("display", "none");
        selectList.attr("data-open", "false");
      }
    }
  });
  
  // this event fires when clicking on an <a> tag
  // this will set the :selected attribute on the <select> and close it
  anchorList.click( (e) => {
    let a = $(e.target).attr("data-value");
    let o = selectTagOption;
    o.each((i, element) => {
      let el = $(element);
      if (el.hasAttr("selected")) {
        el.removeAttr("selected");
      }
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
      let option = $(o[i]);
      let val = option.attr("value");
      if (a === val) {
        option.attr("selected", ""); // set selected item when match is found
        option.change(); // fire the on change event 
        
        // then close it?
        selectList.css("display", "none");
        selectList.attr("data-open", "false");
        break;
      }
    }
  });
      
  selectTag.on("change", (e) => {
    let item = selectTag.find(":selected").text();
    $("#output").html("Selected Country: " + item);
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --select-border: black;
  --select-bgColor: #dcdcdc;
  --select-arrow: var(--select-border);
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

select {
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit; /* I have a particular font for this */
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  outline: none;
}

.select-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  min-width: 15ch;
  max-width: 30ch;
  border: 1px solid var(--select-border);
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.1;
  background-color: var(--select-bgColor);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "select";
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.select-wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 0.5em;
  background-color: var(--select-arrow);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 0%, 50% 100%);
  justify-self: end;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

select, .select-wrapper::after {
  grid-area: select;
}

.option-list {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--select-border);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.option-list a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--select-border);
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.option-list a:hover {
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
}

.select-wrapper select, .option-list a {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<p> Try clicking the select box a few times. </p>
<br>

<!-- The countries are just an example --->
<label for="countries">Select Country: </label>

<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select id="countries">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
  </select>
  <div class="option-list" data-open="false">
    <!-- list of <a></a> tags go here based on the <option> list -->
    <!-- this list also needs to be like a popover not a element that pushes elements -->
  </div>
</div>


<br>
<p id="output">Selected Country: </p>
<br>
<p><strong>UPDATE:</strong> For some reason when clicking the custom list it won't close for some reason! It also blocks elements by pushing them out of the way which I don't want.</p>
```

I don't want to change the code too much because it looks good in design (unless I have to otherwise), and prevent the `<select>` box from opening by default when clicked on so it only shows the custom list but still makes it selectable with a change/input event. I also want to make this into a `class` object so the same(-ish) design and functionality can be reused like this:

```js
class SelectBox { /* some code here */ }


let selectBox1 = new SelectBox(/*... items */);
let selectBox2 = new SelectBox(/* ... items */);

// then append the html somehow?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the CSS display property to `none`. A handy thing to do is to add the option elements as a property to the items in the custom list. Then it is easy to set that option as the selected.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let selectElm = document.forms.form01.countries;
  let labelElm = selectElm.labels[0];
  let ul = document.createElement('UL');
  labelElm.append(ul);
  [...selectElm.options].forEach((option, i) => {
    let li = document.createElement('LI');
    li.innerText = option.innerText;
    li.option = option; // handy hack
    if (i == selectElm.selectedIndex) li.classList.add('selected');
    ul.append(li);
  });
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.option) {
    let ul = e.target.closest('ul');
    ul.classList.toggle('unfold');
    ul.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => li.classList.remove('selected'));
    e.target.classList.add('selected');
    e.target.option.selected = true;
  }
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log([...data]);
});
```

```css
select {
  display: none;
}

label ul {
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
  padding: 0;
  border: thin solid black;
}

label ul li {
  display: none;
}

label ul.unfold li {
  display: block;
}

label ul li.selected {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>
  <select name="countries">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
  </select>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```